# convert decimal? in primitive decimal

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I want to convert nullable decimal to primitive decimal.
How to do this.
I have done some googling and found System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter as one of the solution. But I am not able to figure out how to use it.

```
decimal? offenceAmount = 23;
decimal primitive;
primitive=offenceAmount; //
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
if (offenceAmount.HasValue) {
    primitive = offenceAmount.Value;
}
```

Or, if you want the result to default to `0`:

```
primitive = offenceAmount.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Or a shortcut for the above:

```
primitive = offenseAmount ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`Nullable.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) property:

```
if(offenceAmount.HasValue)
    primitive = offenceAmount.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
primitive = (decimal)offenceAmount;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 primitive = offenceAmount ?? 0;
```